# Import local source file to be compatible with Travis CI

Tags: go, travis-ci, importerror

I have a go project which consists of several packages. First, the main package located at `$GOPATH/src/myproject/main.go`, and then an auth package located at `$GOPATH/src/myproject/auth/<filename>.go`. The main package references the auth package with an `import "myproject/auth"`. Local build goes fine.

Now I try to use this project build with Travis CI, especially to learn more about Travis. Apparently Travis expects `import` statements which don't start with a hostname to be available from beginning, since I get the error `package myproject/auth: unrecognized import path "myproject/auth" (import path does not begin with hostname)`.

On my local machine this is no problem, since my local go knows about its available sources in `$GOPATH`, and so about the project's subpackage, too, and just includes the sources.

What are the expected steps to do to make Travis work with this import statement as well?

Comment: Take a look at the example projects at Travis CI's [homepage, at the bottom](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/go/) to get a feeling for how people usually structure their projects. To my understand, the recommended way to pull external but private dependencies is to use a GitHub API as explained on the same website.

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use full path in import? It does not lead to any problem, right?
It works just fine both local and with CI (hopefully)